# How can I add regular folder to my repository using a Maven build?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-assembly-plugin

Right now if I run my project as a "Maven install", my Java Maven build creates a war file and a zip file, both under the same directory location.

How can I have this build add a regular folder to this directory location, and put the zip file inside that folder?

**More Info**

I tried using the maven-assembly-plugin. In repository.xml, I specify which files to put in my zip. The files are in ${project.basedir}/files. I tried putting the files inside an "extrafolder" so they're at ${project.basedir}/files/extrafolder, hoping this extra folder would be in my local repository, but Maven ignored the folder and still put both the war and zip in the same repository.

Here's the plugin in my POM:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      [...]
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>src/assembly/repository.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
   [...]
</project>
```

And here's the repository.xml file:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">
  <id>repository</id>
  <formats>
    <format>tar</format>
  </formats>
<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory> 
   <fileSets>
         <fileSet>  
           <directory>${project.basedir}/files</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
             <filtered>true</filtered>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.*</include> 
            </includes>           
        </fileSet>         
    </fileSets>  
</assembly>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should configure the outputDirectory as extrafolder if you need it. Example as below:

```
   <fileSets>
     <fileSet>  
       <directory>${project.basedir}/files</directory>
        <outputDirectory>extrafolder</outputDirectory>
         <filtered>true</filtered>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.*</include> 
        </includes>           
    </fileSet>         
</fileSets>
```

To configure the plugin to put the zip file into a specific folder as below:

```
      <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <outputDirectory>extrafolder</outputDirectory>
      <descriptors>
        <descriptor>src/assembly/repository.xml</descriptor>
      </descriptors>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Find more details here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html#outputDirectory

Comment: Using outputDirectory adds a folder **inside** the zip file, but outputDirectory doesn't put the zip file inside a folder. I use Jenkins and Artifactory too, so maybe the solution is in one of these other tools.

Comment: @SammyCakes To add the zip file in a specific directory, you should configure it inside pom.xml in the configuration of the plugin.You can find more details here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/single-mojo.html#outputDirectory